# "Content is not allowed in prolog" ... how to fix? (Python)

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6

I am within my first hour of teaching myself Python. I'm watching a video called ["Python Programming"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4mEzFDjqtA&list=PLT70T66Di3kvga7FsiABEq1U140EiG3j6&index=4) by Derek Banas, and I'm getting stuck already.

As the video suggests, I am using PyCharm with Python 3.6. I have set the project interpreter to Python 3.6 and created a blank project. The video suggests I start on line one with a simple "import random" request, but when I try to run the request, PyCharm gives me the following error message:

> Cannot load settings from file '/Users/josh/PycharmProjects/attempt3/.idea/attempt3.iml': Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in trailing section. Please correct the file content.....

Is this a matter of downloading a certain library or configuring PyCharm settings? How do I download a library to use in PyCharm? How might I configure PyCharm settings to overcome this error?

Comment: Try deleting the attempt3.iml file? iml should be written in xml... not sure where it's getting prolog from

Comment: Yes, the `.iml` file has nothing to do with Python. It appears to be a PyCharm thing (well, IntelliJ IDEA, on which PyCharm is based). Maybe learn Python first and then decide if you want to use PyCharm?

Comment: maybe review some of the 8 setup videos on the PyCharm website, [Getting Started with PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/documentation/), notably the `PyCharm UI and Projects 2/8`, and `Running Python Code 3/8` videos